# With QtCreator, how can I build my project on a remote server I have ssh access to?

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qt-creator, qmake

I need to build an application on a remote server so it can be run locally, where it will issue commands to a website it is hosting. I'm building this application on my machine in QtCreator, but I would like to streamline testing the application by having it build on the remote server.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why not just use a proper build system (think: Jenkins, TeamCity, etc.)?

Comment: @MrEricSir I don't know. Little to no experience with that. What are the main advantages for a fellow doing solo-work?

Answer (score 1):

That first sentence is so long and so confusing... -_-

That said Qt Creator supports **remote deploying and debugging** but not remote building (as far as I know; please someone correct me if I'm wrong).

The only remote-related thing about the building step is cross-compilation which again is performed locally (using a cross-compiler, specifying the sysroot etc.). Of course if the target platform is the same (architecture and installation wise) as the one you use for development the cross-compilation chaos can be completely omitted.

If you want to build Qt-based application (and not only run it) on the remote platform, you will have to setup the development infrastructure (Qt dev libraries, qmake etc.). However, I would suggest using your local system for the development unless the server provides a very noticeable boost during the building step. It's easier that way and makes sense especially if the application that you are building on the remote will be executed locally.

Comment: Interesting that I can deploy... The server is running Centos 6, 64bit, and I'm running ubuntu 16.10 64bit -- does that mean I don't have to run qmake remotely, and can just deploy directly?

Comment: Deploy simply means "Please run the application on the target device and give me feedback on my local one what happens". The only part that `qmake` has in all of this is to define where exactly the binary needs to go from the local to the remote system. That's all. It's the settings in Qt Creator where you tell the IDE things like IP address, password, SSH key etc. and it is used in the project settings for your application but it is not related to `qmake`.

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 options really:

- run the IDE on the remote server and connect using vnc or x2go. This requires a relatively high bandwidth/low latency connection, or the GUI won't be reponsive. This is personally what I do at my work - although we have a dev server set up to mirror prod in our building - so the data connection is great.
- sync your files using [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) and build via commandline. You code-completion will be based on your local machine, so won't be perfect, and you wont be able to double click compile errors, etc. If you are brave you could maybe set up a qt creator build configuration to do this for you, but includes would still be broken.
- use another IDE. NetBeans [supports remote builds](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html). I have never personally used this feature, but I've heard that it works ok.